# Multiplication by an extrinsic matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

I need to project a 2D point taken by a Kinect camera to real world coordinates, without using the official Kinect SDK. I found this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348266/color-space-to-camera-space-transformation-matrix , and it's great.

I just don't understand the following matrices expression:
[image: projection matrix]

The multiplied matrices are of sizes [3x3] and [3x4]. Which gives [3x4]. Obviously this is not invertible. So I'm not sure how to take the inverse of this...

In the answer it says that the matrix on the right (3x4) is the "extrinsic camera matrix", and you can consider it as $(I|0)$ where I is identity matrix.

I read about ["extrinsic matrices"](http://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/22/extrinsic/) but I'm still not sure how this multiplication and inversion is done. I read that you can add a [0 0 0 1] row at the bottom so it becomes a square matrix which is easier to work with. But then I can't multiply it by the left [3x3] matrix (also it will simply become the identity matrix, so it won't do anything).

Can anybody explain how the multiplication and inversion are done? Either mathematically or if there's a module that does that in **python** that'd be great.

Comment: I think the matrix expression is supposed to say that 
$$
\pmatrix{u\\v\\1} = \left[ \pmatrix{f_x & 0 & c_x\\0 & f_y & c_y\\ 0 & 0 & 1}\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0}\right] \pmatrix{X\\Y\\Z\\1}
$$
in other words, $(X,Y,Z)$ is a solution to a linear system of equations

Comment: The problem is that I have (u,v), and I need (X,Y,Z)

Comment: Perhaps you can use a [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore–Penrose_inverse)

Comment: Without more constraints, which presumably the Kinect SDK uses, you can’t back-map a point in the image to a unique point in the scene: image points back-project to _rays_ in the scene.

Comment: @amd what if I want only the (x,y) coordinates?

Comment: What “$(x,y)$ coordinates?” The scene is a three-dimensional space. Do you mean that you’re back-projecting onto the $x$-$y$ plane in the world coordinate system?

Comment: To answer your immediate question, the expression that you’ve quoted from the other answer is nonsensical. The $3\times4$ projection matrix doesn’t have an inverse. You could use the pseudoinverse as @Omnomnomnom suggests, but that’s only going to get you one point on the ray that’s the inverse image of $(u,v)$ (the ray’s point at infinity, IIRC), and likely not the one you want.

Comment: @amd I mean I might be fine with the $(x,y)$ world coordinates, and I don't care about the $z$ coordinate. It can be some range

Comment: The $z$-coordinate matters, though. For the projection matrix in your question, the camera is at the origin, so the intersection of any ray from the camera position is either the camera’s position itself, or the entire ray, neither of which gets you a sensible back-projected point.